# Build package with Webpack containing TypeScript and JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, build, jsx

I have some logic I want to abstract to a local package.
I use yarn workspaces, with the `shared` package being included in the `client` package.

#### What I want

- Use imports like `@acme/shared/utils/withAuth` in the `client` package
- Use React JSX components from the `shared` package, in the `client` package
- Use other functions/hooks/consts  from the `shared` package, in the `client` package

#### What error I encounter now

I build using

```
npx webpack --mode=development
```

On the import

```
import { withAuth } from '@acme/shared/utils/withAuth';
```

I receive the error

```
TypeError: (0 , _acme_shared_utils_withAuth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.withAuth) is not a function
```

### Project structure

```
/client
  /package.json
/shared
  /src
  /dist
  /package.json
/package.json
/tsconfig.json
/webpack.config.js
```

#### /client/package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@acme/shared": "link:../shared/dist",
```

#### /shared/package.json

```json
{
  "name": "@acme/shared",
```

#### /package.json

```json
{
  "name": "acme",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "client",
    "shared"
```

### Config files

#### /tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

#### /webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

// This function will build all files to its location as in the "src" folder.

function getEntries(pattern) {
  const entries = {};

  glob.sync(pattern).forEach((file) => {
    let entryName = file.replace('src/', '');
    entryName = entryName.replace(/.tsx?$/, '.js');
    entries[entryName] = path.join(__dirname, file);
  });

  return entries;
}

module.exports = {
  entry: getEntries('src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

I tried the following:

- Using tsc to build, which gave me the right results without JSX
- Importing with different routes
- Trying to build everything to one file, this seems to have the trouble that I have to export every single file from the entry file and I'm not sure how to import it then
- Tried various solutions by others, but somehow I always ran into some error

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using tsc for now. Apparently I was missing the following rule in the `tsconfig.json`.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "jsx": "react-jsx"
```